# Should I switch to MTL4 from Eigen if I also need to make use of ODEs?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, ode

I'm looking for C++ matrix libraries to work with on a Linux (Fedora) system. The intention is to implement [continuous attractor neural networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor_network) and such for computational neuroscience. I've already begun using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/index.html). However, I realized I need differential equation solvers too for my task and ran into [Odeint](http://headmyshoulder.github.com/odeint-v2/) (which recently seems to have been accepted into boost). Odeint works with MTL4 as [this page details](http://headmyshoulder.github.com/odeint-v2/highlights.html). I'm now wondering if I should rewrite my code using MTL4 instead of Eigen to be able to make use of odeint properly.

I've looked on both google and stackoverflow itself but failed to find a comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that Eigen will also work with odeint. So it is up to you if you want to change to MTL.

The documentation of odeint http://headmyshoulder.github.com/odeint-v2/doc/boost_numeric_odeint/odeint_in_detail/state_types__algebras_and_operations.html shows how to adapt an arbitrary type to odeint. I think Eigen supports expression templates (so you can write vector or matrix expression like `M1=a*M2+b*M3;`) such that you can use odeint with the `vector_space_algebra` and the `default_operations`. All you have to do is to adapt the resizing mechanism of odeint. Have a look at the MTL bindings in odeint to see how this works. It is straightforward.

Comment: Some users reported successful use of odeint with Eigen: http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=108316&p=253887&hilit=ODEint#p253887

Comment: Issue filed at the odeint github tracker: https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2/issues/68